# How to get date month year using loop function

Tags: php

I Wanted to make a function  from where i can get date , month , year 
but i m unable to write functions for that also i don't know how to call those function in Drop down menus

for example

```
function get_date(){
        for($i=1;$i<31;$i++){?>
           <?php return '<option value="$i">  $i </option>';
       }
```

now if i  called it in select menu

```
<select >
 echo get_date();
</select>
```

it returns echo $i kindly guide me where i went wrong

Comment: please specify exactly you want to do so i can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
 <?php
 function get_date()
  {
  $var="";
 for ($i = 1; $i < 31; $i++) {
    $num_padded=sprintf("%02d", $i);
    $var .='<option value="'.$i.'">  '.$num_padded.' </option>';
  }
 return $var;
}
?>
<select >
    <?php echo get_date(); ?>
</select>
```

This one for month

```
<?php
 function get_month()
  {
   $var="";
   for ($m=1; $m<=12; $m++) {
     $var .= '<option value="'.$m.'">'.date('F', mktime(0,0,0,$m, 1,      date('Y'))).' </option>';
}
return $var;
}
?>
<select >
<?php echo get_month(); ?>
</select>
```

This one for Year

```
<?php
function get_year($start,$end){
    $var="";
    while($start <= $end){
        $var .="<option value=".$start.">".$start."</option>";
        $start++;
    }
    return $var;
}
?>
<select >
    <?php echo get_year(1988,2000); ?>
</select>
```

Comment: what if i want the option values to be 01 02 upto 10 then normal onward so i can make a date better date format ?

Comment: thanks you  are great u make this logic so simple and easy to understand especially the second one i was using option value 12 times

Comment: glad to hear it. If this answer help you please give the tick mark

Answer (score 0):

Using variables in strings only works when using double quotes (`"`). Try this:

```
function get_date(){
    $dates = "";
    for($i=1;$i<31;$i++){
        $dates .= "<option value='$i'> $i </option>";
    }

    return $dates;
}
```

Also, there is no need to use php tags in functions.

To call the function you need to put the echo between php tags

```
<select>
    <?php echo get_date(); ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function get_date(){
        $date = "";
        for($i=1;$i<31;$i++){              
           $date .=  '<option value="'.$i.'>'.$i.'</option>';                
        }
        return $date;
}
```

Comment: it return $i 30 time but why not the value

Comment: @muhammad usman : its not return 30 time, its just return only one time.
and I edited my answer .

Answer (score 0):

Create a string with all options and then return

```
function get_date(){
  $options = "";
  for($i=1;$i<31;$i++){
    $options .= "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
  }
  return $options;
}
```

And then print like this

```
<select name="nameofdropdown" id="idofdropdown">
<?php echo get_date(); ?>
</select>
```

**Check your errors**

1. If you return if immediate return and stop iterations.
2. Php variables inside singel quotes will not evaluates like `'$i'`  it must be `"$i"` or `"'$i'"`within single qotes
3. Use php tag `<?php ?>` to print function returned value.

Comment: There would be many good answer if you specify your intention clearly. I know you want to create drop-down for month but it varies by month like in fab its onyl 28 for that what you have though ?

Comment: well i m not handling it my basic purpose was to run that function which you all helped and i did almost all the things and i ll surely careful to write more specific questions

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
function get_date(){
    for($i=1;$i<31;$i++){?>
       <?php return '<option value="'.$i.'">  '.$i.' </option>';
   }
```